# Bonjour: Can not ping through serviceName on Windows

Tags: bonjour

I develop our application and can succeed to get hotsname through func: ServiceFound(DNSSDService sref, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, String serviceName, String regType, String domain)

I checked the wireshark and Log, the serviceName is right.

My question: 
      Why I can not ping it through "serviceName.domain", e.g: ping serviceName.local. (I want to use ping to test the network available beofre run my application. now it is blocked the failed ping)
      But I can ping it through the real IP, e.g: ping 1.2.3.4  (This means that the network is ok)

ServiceFound and ServiceResolved only provide serviceName.

So how to solve this problem: 
     1) one simple way to get IP
    or 2) how to solve the problem of "ping serviceName.local"

Thanks a lot for your support in advance!

***************************************Update******************
I retest it on other PC:

I use dns-sd.exe to debug the network

Using following command can get servicename

$ dns-sd.exe -B _http._tcp

Browsing for _http._tcp
Timestamp     A/R Flags if Domain          Service Type              Instance Name
 4:33:52.663  Add     3  3 local.          _http._tcp.               test

Using following command can get zone file

$ dns-sd.exe -Z _http._tcp

Browsing for _http._tcp
_http._tcp                                      PTR     Officejet\032Pro\032L7500\032[FEDCE8]._http._tcp
Officejet\032Pro\032L7500\032[FEDCE8]._http._tcp SRV     0 0 80 HPFEDCE8.local. ; Replace with unicast FQDN of target host
Officejet\032Pro\032L7500\032[FEDCE8]._http._tcp TXT     ""

using following command can get IP (based on HPFEDCE8.local. in above feedback)

$ dns-sd.exe -G v4 HPFEDCE8.local.

Timestamp     A/R Flags if Hostname         Address                    TTL
 4:43:38.965  Add     2  3 bej1301Dell2360.local.    10.61.20.99        240

So I can ping it through HPFEDCE8.local.

But in my Test PC: "$ dns-sd.exe -B _http._tcp" is ok, but others commands are failed.

So I think this is the root cause.
  So my question is:
    as I know, we can use "instance Name" to generate the hostname: test.local.
       why they are different from "HPFEDCE8.local." in the zone file
    why "ping HPFEDCE8.local." ok and "ping test.local." failed

Do you have any others ideas for my Test PC?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: who can help it?   I also have checked the firewall configuration refer to apple web description.  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Help: Question for your confirm,